# Cambiar idioma de frontend a español en Magento 2

Tags: magento2, idioma, theme

Estoy creando un sitio en Magento versión 2.3.4, he comprado e instalado una plantilla para el theme y hasta ahí todo bien. Después he creado un tema hijo (child theme) que hereda del tema de la plantilla y lo estoy usando como tema por defecto para la página. También he cambiado el idioma local desde la página del administrador.

La plantilla trae un archivo de traducción a español aunque faltan muchas frases, dentro de mi carpeta del tema hijo he creado la carpeta i18n y he pegado el csv de traducción de la plantilla agregando yo algunas traducciones a las frases que aparecen en la página principal pero no consigo que cambie el idioma.

Si alguien sabe si no estoy creando la carpeta donde debería o por qué puede estar fallando (quizás por el tema hijo) o si hay algún paquete de traducción que pueda instalar y modificar el archivo de traducción con las frases de la plantilla para modificar el idioma del frontend agradecería su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si alguien más tiene esta duda, dejo un link de descarga al paquete en español (de España) de Mageplaza.
[https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-spanish-language-pack]

Si necesitais español de otros países buscad en Mageplaza, tiene para muchos paises.

Se instala el módulo y en **app/i18n/Mageplaza/es_es/es_ES.csv** se añaden las frases que no vengan traducidas en el paquete de la siguiente forma:

```
"text in english","texto que quieres que aparezca"
```

Después de modificar el es_ES.csv hay que lanzar los siguientes comandos desde la consola:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES en_US -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Si después de esto no se han efectuado los cambios pertinentes puede ser que la frase que intentas traducir no tenga una función de traducción donde se está creando. Entonces debes buscar la plantilla o xml donde se encuentra ese texto y añadir tu mismo la función de traducción, después de esto podrás traducirlo desde el es_ES.csv